# Import-SPWeb not importing Custom Person / Group Column Values

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, export, import, person

I have a SharePoint 2013 Multi-Tenant farm configured to use FBA. I tried exporting a site in one of the site collections of the tenant using Export-SPWeb. I did include the option IncludeUserSecurity. I have Custom Person / Group columns in most of my custom lists. But after I imported this in a target site in a different farm, everything worked fine, except that the values for these Custom Person / Group columns did not get imported (though I used the IncludeUserSecurity option while importing also), although the OOTB Created By and Modified By column values seem to be getting imported. Can anyone please tell me, if this is possible during Export & Import of SPWeb using PowerShell? I understand that IncludeUserSecurity option is only to preserve security.